# lightning:input field hidden

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I created a lightning component with lightning:recordEditForm and lightning:inputField to create a new record.

I have another field which I don't want it to be in the form but I want to populate it.

I didn't find a way to do this without put it in the form and use "slds-hidden" but that makes a gap in the UI.

Does someone know what to do in that case ?
I mean, is there a better way to hide the field ?
Or maybe a solution to "remove" the gap ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `slds-hide` instead of `slds-hidden`.

Comment: Thanks ! slds-hide worked !!! I didn't event know it exists.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7, add your answer =P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `slds-hide` instead of `slds-hidden`.

So the thing is if you just want to disappear the element from the UI then use the `slds-hidden` and it will take its space.

And to remove the space as well use the `slds-hide`.